# How to disable Launch when ready checkbox when installing appx bundle?

Tags: windows, installation, uwp, windows-installer, appxmanifest

For our **sideloaded** application we need to disable the user to start the UWP application after install or update.

I went through the package manifest and all of the properties without success in finding a way to disable the **Launch when ready** checkbox and **Launch button**.

Any idea is appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid it's *not* possible to modify or customize the installation UI to hide the **Launch** button or disable the **Launch when ready** checkbox.

Custom installation dialogs are not supported when using MSIX or APPX.

Answer (score 1):

> For our sideloaded application we need to disable the user to start the UWP application after install or update.

For your requirement, we suggest your add [splash screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen#complete-code) for the app. And store current app's version to [LoclSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data), when you launch the app please compare current version with LocalSetting value in the splash screen, if they are different, you could hidden `DismissSplash` button that make app will not navigate main page.

```
public static string GetAppVersion()
{
    Package package = Package.Current;
    PackageId packageId = package.Id;
    PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;

    return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);
}
```

Comment: This could provide a workaround and solution, but i would need to constantly check if some files are available in directory before dismissing the splashscreen. UX would be way better to be able to disable launch at start and just finish the installation without user to be able Launch using the button.

Comment: I mean User eXperience, building software components to provide the user with ability to achieve more with less clicks. There might be some other more verbose definition, but that is how i see it.